# Stream Closed IO Exception Java - android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ioexception, fileinputstream

I'am trying to zip a sub folder and getting an Stream Closed exception

```
private static void zipSubFolder(ZipOutputStream out, File folder, int basePathLength) throws IOException{
            final int BUFFER = 2048;
    
            File[] fileList = folder.listFiles();
            BufferedInputStream origin = null;
            for (File file : fileList) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    zipSubFolder(out, file, basePathLength);
                } else {
                    byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER];
                    String unmodifiedFilePath = file.getPath();
                    String relativePath = unmodifiedFilePath
                            .substring(basePathLength);
                    try (FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(unmodifiedFilePath)) {
                        origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);
                    }
                    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(relativePath);
                    entry.setTime(file.lastModified()); // to keep modification time after unzipping
                    out.putNextEntry(entry);
                    int count;
                    while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                        out.write(data, 0, count);
                    }
                    origin.close();
                }
            }
        }
```

getting error in line this:
while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1)

```
: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:313)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your try resource statement would close FileInputStream fi as soon as you left {} brackets. try to put the whole code inside try resource brackets.

from java doc:
A BufferedInputStream adds functionality to another input stream-namely, the ability to buffer the input and to support the mark and reset methods. When the BufferedInputStream is created, an internal buffer array is created. As bytes from the stream are read or skipped, the internal buffer is refilled as necessary from the contained input stream, many bytes at a time. The mark operation remembers a point in the input stream and the reset operation causes all the bytes read since the most recent mark operation to be reread before new bytes are taken from the contained input stream.